# Orden en Cloudfirestore de inserción de documentos en una colección, usando Angularfire

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Tengo una colección llamada "Autores" en **Cloud Firestore** de **Firebase**. Para guardar los datos uso la librería **Angularfire**. Tengo un servicio en el cual uso un método para guardar los datos de cada nuevo autor que quiero agregar a la colección **Autores**:

```html
agregarAutor(Autor: ShirtId)
{
     return this.shirtCollection.add(Autor);
}
```

El problema es que los nuevos documentos se van guardando en la colección con un orden aleatorio. Sin tener el cuenta el orden cronológico en el cual los he guardado. No ´se qué criterio usa **Cloud Firestore** para ordenar los documentos según se van insertando

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Están ordenados alfabeticamente por id, el cual es aleatorio. Es decir que no están ordenados. Si quieres recibirlos en el orden que los agregaste, debes registrar ese orden en algún campo de los documentos. Lo mejor es que uses un timestamp:

```
this.shirtCollection.add({
    edad: "212",
    nombre: "asd",
    timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
});
```

`serverTimestamp()` es el momento exacto en el que el documento llega a los servidores de firebase, con nanosegundos incluidos. Es mucho más confiable que tomar la hora del dispositivo cliente.
Luego usas ese campo como parámetro para ordenar los resultados:

```
this.shirtCollection.orderBy("timestamp")
```

La razón por la que no hay campos autoincrementables en firestore es porque está diseñado para ser altamente escalable (mucho más que una base de datos relacional) y estos tipos de campos se vuelven inestables cuando tienes muchas escrituras por segundo. Puedes leer mas sobre esto [acá](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/best-practices#hotspots).

Comment: Ok. Pensaba que había alguna forma de ordenarlos sin más. Vengo del mundo de Mysql y pensaba que había alguna forma de hacer como los campos autonuméricos y guardar las cosas en orden. Ese tiempo "serverTimestamp" lo coge del propio servidor de Firebase? Si coge l hora del propio servidor, supongo que será de fiar.

Comment: respuesta editada

Answer (score 0):

La verdad es que no sé como implementar esas líneas de código:

```html
timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

Qué módulos tengo que importar en el app.module.ts o en el componente?
Adjunto mi componente:

```html
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection} from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable, from, Timestamp } from 'rxjs';
import {auditTime, map} from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Autor } from '../modelos/autor/autor.module';
import {FormControl, FormGroup} from   '@angular/forms';


export interface Shirt { nombre_autor: string; edad: number }
export interface ShirtId extends Shirt {id: string;}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class ServiciocrudService {

  private shirtCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Shirt>;
  shirts: Observable<ShirtId[]>;

  public seleccionado: ShirtId =  {
    id: null,
    edad: undefined,
    nombre_autor: ''
  };



  constructor(private readonly afs: AngularFirestore) {

    this.shirtCollection = afs.collection<Shirt>('autores');
    // .snapshotChanges() returns a DocumentChangeAction[], which contains
    // a lot of information about "what happened" with each change. If you want to
    // get the data and the id use the map operator.
    this.shirts = this.shirtCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => actions.map(a => {
        const data = a.payload.doc.data() as Shirt;
        const id = a.payload.doc.id;
        return { id, ...data };
      }))
    );

    
   }

   retornar2(){
    return this.shirts;
   }

   editarAutor(Autor: ShirtId)
   {
      let identificador= Autor.id;
      return this.shirtCollection.doc(identificador).update(Autor);
   }


   borrarAutor(id: string)
   {
     return this.shirtCollection.doc(id).delete();

   }

   agregarAutor(Autor: Shirt)
   {
     return this.shirtCollection.add(Autor);
   }
}
```